# creating shadow effect

Tags: shadows, drop-shadow

[image]

[image]

I was trying to make a rocket but I am stuck with the shadow portion. How can I create a shadow that looks like picture 2?

Comment: What software are you using? It helps to know...

Comment: adobe cc 2015 is my software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using it in Illustrator I would :

1. get the main shape that is part of that rocket. With the same color, you are using there.
2. copy and past in the same place (cmd+shift+V) twice.
3. offset one of them to the left and use the pathfinder tool as shown in the images

[image]
 [image: List item]

The result should be a shape like this

[image]

4. Then set that object to a transparency mode 'multiply' as such

[image]

5. finally you would have to arrange the objects in a way where this new shadow would be over the main shape and the top darker part of the rocket but not over the circular shape. So select the dark point of the rocket and the background shape and the shadow and arrange them to be sent to back.

[image]

One last thing would be adjusting the opacity of the shadow shape. I used 50% opacity for this result

[image]

Hope this helps :) Any doubts let me know. This was done in illustrator.
Also apologies for the rushed version of your lovely illustration.

Comment: Firstly many thanks to you for such detailed steps I have been searching for long. Secondly, though the process works fine when I try to change the transparency to multiply the color changes. like if it was originally orange, when I use multiply option,  the color seems like reddish ornage. I can't show you here. Lastly, is it possible to connect with you some other media like behance or fb?  I work as  clerk  and it's really boring ,I want to switch to graphics field .But, I need some advice about how to proceed, what to follow , maybe ask steps  like this when I'm stuck.